# Login form combobox entity framework error

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to make a login form but I can not figure out how to retrieve the username from the combobox i did so:

xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid Height="274">
        <Label Content="LOGGARSI PER ENTRARE" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Sitka Heading" Margin="0,0,0,230"  />
        <Label Content="Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="userName" SelectedValuePath="userName" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=userName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="209,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Content="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LabelStyle}"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="passBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="209,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="30"/>
        <Button x:Name="BtnLogIn" Content="Entra" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,204,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Click="BtnLogIn_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

this is code be in:

```
NioRepairContext ctx;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FillComboUsers();
}

public List<User> user { get; set; }
private void FillComboUsers()
{
    ctx = new NioRepairContext();
    var item = ctx.Users.ToList();
    user = item;
    DataContext = user;
}

private void BtnLogIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var user = ctx.Users.Where(i => i.userName == ComboUsers.SelectedItem.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
    if (user == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Fallito, Credenziali inesatte");
    }
    if (user.userName == ComboUsers.SelectedItem.ToString() && user.password == passBox.Password.ToString())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Benvenuto " + user.userName+ ", Login Corretto");   
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Fallito, Credenziali inesatte");   
    }
}
```

I can not understand if I hacked the combobox binding or other

Answer (score 1):

Since you have bound the `ItemsSource` property to your `List<User>`, you could get the selected user using the `SelectedItem` property:

```
var selectedUser = ComboUsers.SelectedItem as User;
string name = selectedUser.userName;
```

You migth as well remove the `SelectedItem` and the `SelectedValuePath` attributes from your XAML since you don't have any source properties to bind to:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="userName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="209,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer then: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow